# How to print a wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to print everything within a wpf control - lets say a grid.

I read about printvisual method, but its not visible to me.

My code looks like this:

```
private void print(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        printDlg.PrintVisual(element, "this is a test");
    }
```

and my compiler says does not contain a definition for PrintVisual method. I already included  System.Windows.Media.Visual namespace but that didnt help aswell.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have the wrong using :

`using System.Windows.Forms;` instead of `using System.Windows.Controls;`

The `PrintDialog` is in both but one doesn't have the `PrintVisual()` method.

Comment: the other way round fixed my problem. i was using System.Windows.Forms, what i needed was System.Windows.Controls.